# How to remove firebase analytics from sub module android?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-analytics

When I try to add analytics in my project I got this error

Execution failed for task ':countrycodepicker:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     D:\Think 42 labs\Rizek users\users\countrycodepicker\src\nullnull\google-services.json
>     D:\Think 42 labs\Rizek users\users\countrycodepicker\src\debug\google-services.json
>     D:\Think 42 labs\Rizek users\users\countrycodepicker\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
>     D:\Think 42 labs\Rizek users\users\countrycodepicker\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
>     D:\Think 42 labs\Rizek users\users\countrycodepicker\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
>     D:\Think 42 labs\Rizek users\users\countrycodepicker\google-services.json

this is my Gradle file for app module

```
  {   
 //Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
//Country picker
implementation project(':countrycodepicker')
 }
```

Comment: `google-services.json`, It's cleary stating here *File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.*

Comment: Its already already in app module

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [follow the instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to add Firebase to your app.  Especially the [step where you download the configuration file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file) and add it to your project.

Comment: If you're seeing that error, it's not implemented correctly.